# How to use backwards slash in front of a quotation?

Tags: java

I was wondering how to put a backwards slash in front of a quotation mark in java, without having it make the quotation mark a string, and use the backward slash.

```
System.out.println("This is a backwards slash \");
```

Comment: If you're talking about printing a backslash to the console: `System.out.println("This is a backwards slash \\");`

Comment: but then is makes the quotation a string

Comment: Then I might be misunderstanding. You want to print a backslash to console, or something else?

Comment: I am using it a a file directory

Comment: I agree with @AntonH. Either you want to print a \ or you want to print a ". Which one is it?

Comment: If you want to use a backslash like in a Windows directory string, you need to double the backslashes: `C:\\one\\example\\string.txt`.

Comment: Files.copy("Users\\" + userName + "\Downloads", "Users\\" + userName + "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup", REPLACE_EXISTING);

Comment: Thats an example that better suits the situation

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in Java strings. So if you need one backslash, you precede it with a backslash `"\\"`. If you need 2 backslashes, you escape both: `"\\\\"`. And so on. So if you want to print "Users\\", you need to put `"Users\\\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character is used to escape characters. So in order to use the backslash you need to escape it

```
System.out.println("This is a backwards slash \\");
```

Comment: Now with that an error occurs after \Downloads saying it is an invalid escape sequence

Comment: Because you need `"\\Downloads"`

Comment: @Kieran Well you need \\ in the string literal *anytime* you want to represent a backslash...